# Problems creating linked list in while loop. Getting runtime error on second run in loop

Tags: list, while-loop, linked-list, strncpy

I am writing a program that puts each line of a text in a node in a linked list. I want to create a new node for each line in the text. Program crashes during second run in while loop. After some testing I think it has to do with the strncpy-function, but not sure. Where am I going wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXBUF 50

struct node
{
    char data[MAXBUF];
    struct node *next;
};

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    if (f == NULL) exit("ERROR\n");

    struct node *root = NULL;
    struct node *pointer = NULL;

    root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    pointer = root;

    char buf[MAXBUF];
    while(fgets(buf, MAXBUF, f) != NULL)
    {
        strncpy(pointer->data, buf, MAXBUF);
        pointer->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        pointer->next = NULL;
        pointer = pointer->next;
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pointer->next = NULL;
pointer = pointer->next;
```

Thus next time round the loop:

```
while(fgets(buf, MAXBUF, f) != NULL)
    {
        strncpy(pointer->data, buf, MAXBUF);
```

pointer->data will deference NULL. You probably want to test pointer for NULL before strncpy and create a malloc'd node there.

Note that you never seem to free any of these nodes either.